# PHP вытянуть данные из файла

Tags: php, строки

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Есть файл с данными (/var/www/html/data.php) в нем через пробел прописано -  3 5 18 в одну строку. 
Как эти данные вытащить как разные переменные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый просто пример и не обязательно лучший.

```
$data = file_get_contents("file_path");
$arrayValue = explode(' ', $data); 
list($value1, $value2, $value3, $value4) = $data;
```

Теперь все переменные будут иметь первые 4 значения которые были разделены пробелами в файле, тут я обращаю ваше внимание на ту функцию которую я использовал для открытия файла, вам может подходить другая(работаете с файлами на сервер), например `fopen`.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.